# Compile a C program using Command prompt

Tags: compilation, command-line-interface, command-prompt

My Task-Finding Area of a circle using command line interface in windows. I created a file named circle.c and tried to compile with command prompt. But shows error as -**'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file**-.
I tried searching in the web. It shows me to open Developer command prompt. But I don't have any Visual Studio installed on my pc. 
How can I run this program using command line interface?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
float Diameter=atoi(argv[1]);
float radius=D/2;
float area=(radius*radius)*3.14;
printf("The area is %0.2f",area);
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"But i don't have any Visual Studio installed in my pc."* - How about installing Visual Studio on your PC?

Comment: You don't have VS installed so you either need to install it or use another compiler.

Comment: Oh, Turbo C? Is there a particular reason you want to use that? It is ancient.

Comment: Suggest me another compiler which could be used as command line interface.

Comment: Actually, I'm job recruitment process they are asking to compile and run using command line arguments. So i am trying to learn using this.

Comment: Is this compulsory necessary to install Visual Studio?@andreee

Comment: gcc might be a better option: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html (I use VS so can't really say). There is a free edition of VS (Community) which should come with command line and IDE options. Also, it looks like the compiler for Turbo C++ is `tcc` (not `cl`): [How to compile and run Turbo compiler (windows 7) in command prompt](//stackoverflow.com/q/19035775)